# do LP and Swap by using uiniswap V2 in Sepolia Testnet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens, uniswap

I deployed a contract on the Sepolia Testnet to facilitate Liquidity Provision (LP) and swapping using Uniswap V2. The deployed contract can be found at the address: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x38b5608570ab32a2734b074aeac2bf7a3ad2ca00.

The source code is accessible via the aforementioned link. Following the deployment, the LP was successfully created. After the initial transfer, which worked well, I changed the allow_swap variable to true from its default false value. Then, I attempted a second transfer after invoking the setAllowSwap function to enable swapping within the _transfer function. However, I encountered a gas estimation error. This issue arose due to a problem with the code, but I am unsure of the specific cause.is there any solution or any contract with Uniswap v2 that works well in Sepolia test net.

```
    function swapAndLiquify() public lockTheSwap {
        uint256 totalTokens = balanceOf(address(this));
        swapTokensForEth(totalTokens);
        

    }

    //swap for eth is to support the converstion of tokens to weth during swapandliquify this is a supporting function
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = WETH;
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this), // The contract
            block.timestamp
        );

        emit SwapTokensForETH(tokenAmount, path);
    }
```

thanks in advance